# Eloquent cannot find tables that are ends with `datas`

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I made a DB table in Laravel 6.6 that ends with `datas` like following:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\voiceit> php artisan make:migration create_org_datas_table
Created Migration: 2019_12_16_094613_create_org_datas_table
```

I respected the rule that Laravel ORM needs plural names for the tables. Also, I generated the relative model, controller and resource:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\voiceit> php artisan make:controller  API\OrgDataController --api -m OrgData
Controller created successfully.
C:\xampp\htdocs\voiceit> php artisan make:resource OrgData
Resource created successfully.
```

and finally I did the migration:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\voiceit> php artisan migrate
```

I checked my DB manually and it generated the `org_datas` table correctly in the DB.

However when I try to run a simple query like this:

```
$orgDatas = OrgData::all();
```

it generates the following error:

> "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'mjzsoft.org_data' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from org_data)"

if in the model I add the following line of code then it can find the table:

```
class OrgData extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'org_datas';
}
```

Now the question is, does the `data` is a special case or is it because that the word `data` does not have plural form or something else? If this is the case then `*_informations` also must not work and I need to clarify for the Laravel the name of the table!? Or maybe I missed something that it does not detect the correct name of the table!?

Comment: `data` is the plural form, plural of `data` is `data`, plural of `datum` is `data` ... so `data` is uncountable to the pluralizer

Comment: you may need to specify the table name explicitly in your model. ;)

Comment: As I said I did it already. That is not the problem. What I like to know does the Laravel artisan check the English Dictionary and then makes decision regarding the table names in the query???? If I make the table names based on German language what would happen then?

Comment: yes it is based on english there is a Pluralizer that is used and it defines the rules and exceptions as well as other libraries to determine these words ... if you dont want the naming convention to be 'guessed' for you, just define the table names yourself; there is nothing wrong with being explicit

Comment: The convention is: You name the model after a row of your data and your table after a collection of your data. For example the table would be called `users` because it contains users but the model will be called `User` because a single row is a single user. It does use a pluraliser to work out the singlar/plural forms but it's a bit inaccurate to claim that it uses the English dictionary. It just uses basic pluralisation rules. What you are doing by explicitly declaring the name *should* work and is what you should be doing if using "unconventional" table names.

Comment: This is something that I am interested to know but couldn't find any official recourse for that. If it uses some rules then it must apply on any languages and names that we use and I like to know those rules. If it use a dictionary then creating name in other languages must be fine and will makes the logic of pluraliser not works correctly. For me that is not a native English speaker only a simple logic that adds a single `s` at the end of the names makes more sense rather than looking the variable names linguistically.

Comment: I think you are creating way to much concern about something that has clearly been explained why, i have created multiple models through my career and this has not at all been a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have states this is not a questionable issue for English speakers, you can look at Laravel's Pluralizer [laravel/frameork/Illuminate/Support/Pluralizer.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Pluralizer.php) which states that `data` has been specifically identified as a word which will not be pluralized along with a list of other words.

Comment: Thanks. That is the list I was looking for. audio,
bison,
cattle,
chassis,
compensation,
coreopsis,
data,
deer,
education,
emoji,
equipment,
evidence,
feedback,
firmware,
fish,
furniture,
gold,
hardware,
information,
jedi,
kin,
knowledge,
love,
metadata,
money,
moose,
news,
nutrition,
offspring,
plankton,
pokemon,
police,
rain,
recommended,
related,
rice,
series,
sheep,
software,
species,
swine,
traffic,
wheat.

Comment: So now it is clear that it does not use any dictionary.